# What is the inverse of the eigenvector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I see in a lot of resources that state that in order to find the inverse matrix using the eigendecomposition (for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Matrix_inverse_via_eigendecomposition)) ,
One needs to decompose A to its eigenvectors and eigenvalues, 
And then, using the fact that the eigenvalues matrix $\Lambda$ is diagonal, the inverse is straightforward.
But, why is no one discussing how to compute the inverse of the eigenvector matrix?
 I'm probably missing something trivial, but trying to prove myself that $Q^{-1}=Q^T$, or another way to calculate $Q^{-1}$ didn't succeed.
So, how do we calculate $Q^-1$ in order to find $A$?

Answer (score 3):

We compute the inverse of $Q$ just the same way we compute the inverse of any other matrix. There is nothing peculiar here just because we are working with eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: If so, so how can we find the inverse of $A$ using the decomposition, if to find the inverse of $Q$ we again need to find the decomposition and so on? Maybe the question should by : What is exactly the algorithm to find $A^{-1}$ assuming we have $\Lambda$ and $Q$.

Comment: *If* we already have $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, then $A^{-1}=Q\Lambda^{-1}Q^{-1}$ (assuming that $0$ is not an eigenvalue), but that is *not* a natural way of computing $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is only saying that, given the decomposition $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, the inverse of $A$ is $A^{-1}= Q \Lambda^{-1} Q^{-1}$ and moreover $\Lambda^{-1}$ can be obtained by inverting the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$. One way you can think about this is that $A^{-1}$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$, but the eigenvalues are inverted. I don't think that section of the Wikipedia article is intended as a statement about how to compute inverses in practice.

Comment: Thank you for clearing their intent, but isn't there an algorithm to find the inverse of a matrix using its decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to calculate the inverse, then you have gone a longer way than necessary if you do it through a diagonalisation. You have to invert some matrix anyway, and I see no a priori reason why $Q$ should be easier to invert than $A$ (one exception is if $A$ is symmetric, where inversion of $Q$ amounts to taking the transpose, if you just choose its columns right).

However, the diagonalisation is very useful for other things. For instance, calculating high powers of $A$ is a lot easier to do after diagonalisation, because then you're just calculating high powers of a diagonal matrix. If you need to do such things in addition to calculating the inverse of $A$, then "spending" your inverse calculation on $Q^{-1}$ rather than $A^{-1}$ will likely be a good idea.